# SiriKit: How to set output property when intent is handled in the main app?

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts, intents-extension

## Context

I'm working on adding support for Siri Shortcuts (Intents?) to a non-trivial app. My main goal is to allow users to automatise some tasks within the app using Shortcuts.app.

I have defined `MyIntent` in the `Intents.intentdefinition` in the `Intents Extension` target, together with `MyIntentResponse`, which has an output property `file: INFile`.

Given the non-trivial nature of the app, I'm forwarding the intent from `Intent Extension` to the main app:

```
    func handle(intent: MyIntent, completion: @escaping (MyIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        // Can't handle the intent in the app extension yet, let the main app handle it
        let response = MyIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: nil)

        // TODO: How to update the response (with an output property) if the intent continues in the app?
        completion(response)
    }
```

## Problem

Once the intent is forwarded to the app, the `AppDelegate.application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` method is called with a user activity which also has the property `interaction: INInteraction?` set.

From the provided `INInteraction` I can get both the `intent: INIntent` and `response: INIntentResponse` to handle the intent accordingly.

What's missing, however, is a way how to communicate back to the Shortcuts.app about the result of the intent and provide the desired output property (`file: INFile`).

## Question

Is there a way how to provide an intent response with an output property set if the intent is handled in the main app?

## Details

Interestingly, there's a `AppDelegate` method that should handle this use case:

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                   handle intent: INIntent, 
        completionHandler: @escaping (INIntentResponse) -> Void)
```

And the documentation says:

> An app with an Intents app extension can use this method to handle an intent directly, instead of handling it in the app extension. You might use this method to implement workflows that you cannot implement easily in your extension. For example, you might use it to start or manage a user's workout session. If your app is not running, SiriKit launches your app in the background so that the Siri interface remains active.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/2887573-application

In theory, it should be possible just to call the `completionHandler` with a newly instantiated `MyIntentResponse` which would have `file` property set correctly.

However, this method is never called. Instead, the above mentioned `AppDelegate.application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` is called.

Comment: Seems like this is not possible: "... once you continueInApp, the intents extension finishes, you can’t return data to it." -- https://twitter.com/ToolboxProApp/status/1237702790769672198

Answer (score 0):

If you use .handleInApp instead of .continueInApp in your Intents extension handle() function, then your app delegate's handleIntent() function will be called instead of the continue:restorationHandler() function. This will allow you to pass back INIntentResponse back to the extension in the completionHandler.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no `.handleInApp` in the Xcode-generated `MyIntentResponseCode` so I can't use it. Only `.continueInApp` and several others as described in the documentation: "Xcode automatically creates the following response codes for a custom intent: unspecified, ready, continueInApp, inProgress, success, failure, and failureRequiringAppLaunch." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app

Comment: Interesting. I use .handleInApp with SiriKit Media Intents and I see it in the apple documentation for INStartWorkoutIntentResponse. It might still work in routing to appDelegate.handleIntent(). Regardless, you might want to look into donating shortcuts as described here and elsewhere: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts . That's how you tell Siri about your app's UserActivities.